# Weird armature deformation?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

So I'm working on rigging a skeleton for a character, and while testing armature deformation part of the torso stayed behind and stretched out. I'm sure it's my own incompetence causing this, but I'm not sure what specifically is causing this. Could it be something with the armature modifier (which is bound to just the bone envelopes) I have applied to the torso? Or the bone or torso parenting?

[image: How it looks normally.]
[image: How it looks when I rotate the lower spine bone.]

Answer (score 2):

Its to do with vertex groups and bone weight painting. Your upper geometry vertices are not weighted to the expected bones so wont move, conversely vertices assigned the wrong weighting to incorrect bones will also move in an unwanted fashion.

A simple demonstration with two bones and a cylinder, parent the cylinder geometry to the bone armature and select "armature deform > with automatic weights". The software will automatically assign the geometry vertices to what it thinks is the nearest bone, then go into pose mode of the armature and bend a bone, the geometry should bend as expected:

[image]

Next if you go into edit mode of the geometry with vertices visible, in the panel on the RHS under "Object Data Properties" (green triangle connecting three circles symbol), you will be able to select specific vertices and assign them or remove them from specific bones in the list of your armature (in rigging it helps to name all of your bone correctly for this exact purpose), in this example I have wrongly selected vertices at the root of the cylinder and assigned them to the front bone:

[image]

Now when I go into edit mode for the armature and pose mode and rotate the front bone the vertices of the root of the cylinder just vertex weight assigned move too:

[image]

For organic objects you can weight paint small amounts to each vertex then smooth or average them out so they have some weighted influence by two nearby bones for a more organic bend. In your case, another option if the robot is meant to be a solid object per piece, you can just parent each solid piece of geometry to a specific bone, because it's solid it won't deform when rotating bones.