# Armature not moving Object- on any projects!

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, bones

Whenever I follow the basic steps of making and parenting an armature, it doesn’t have any effect. The bones still don’t affect the mesh despite being visibly parented. I have the wiggle bones add-on enabled, but non of its motion works with the mesh- it’s as though it’s unattatched despite menus and such indicating it’s been parented. I can go to the weight paint mode, but there’s no “paint” on the mesh- when it on manually there’s also no effect.
Interestingly this seems to not just be limited to my current project- when I open a new file and try to parent an armature with the default cube, the same issue occurs. Is there some setting somewhere messing up the ability for the bones to connect with the mesh? I’ve done my best to research but I’m super duper beginner and things quickly get beyond my ability to understand. Any advice? Happy to supply more info

Update: a big massive thanks to everyone who reached out with help, I genuinely really appreciate it, but with the stress it’s been causing me I think I’ll be putting things with blender on hiatus. Again thanks for your help but I’m not up to putting more time into this issue for now.

Comment: I've provided a basic rigging example here which may be of some use: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/295502/weird-armature-deformation/295516#295516

Comment: Please share a simple blend file which you've rigged but isn't working so that we can see where you're going wrong.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it

Comment: You need to tell us more about your workflow, my first guess would be: You didn't choose "With Automatic Weights" when parenting the cube to the armature